# How to tell VsCodium and VsCode apart?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodium

Without having done the installation myself, is there an easy way to check (maybe from within the application) if it is VsCode or VsCodium?

Answer (score 1):

The [env namespace](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#env) has a property `appName` that lets you tell apart which version is running.

**Example**

```js
import { env } from 'vscode';

switch (env.appName) {
  case 'VSCodium':
  case 'VSCodium - Insiders':
    console.log('You are using VSCodium');
    break;

  case 'Visual Studio Code':
  case 'Visual Studio Code - Insiders':
    console.log('You are using Visual Studio Code');
    break;

  default:
    console.log('You are using a different flavour of VSCode');
    break;
}
```